# How do I prevent my Linux service (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS) from restarting when using loops that run in the background?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, service

So I have a script setup that I want to run as a service. The script runs 8 curl commands continuously forever:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
threads=8
check_interval=15
batch_url=https://myurl.com

for ((i = 0 ; i < threads ; i++)); do
  sleep $i
  while true; do
    sleep 0.5
    has_items=$(curl --silent -m 15.0 --connect-timeout 1.5 $batch_url/$i)
    if [ "$has_items" == "false" ]; then
      sleep ${check_interval}
      continue
    fi
  done &
done
```

I have a service file setup in `systemd` that looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run the batch forever
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/my_script_location

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I simply run the script it works fine. It loops forever pinging URLs `/0` through `/7` forever.

However, if I set it up as a service, the service will restart after some time.

I believe the issue is related to having the `while` loop run in the background, but not sure how to make the service work with this. It's possible that the service approach is the wrong method. I simply need this script to always remain running.

Comment: Replace `simple` with `oneshot`?

Comment: @Cyrus When using `oneshot`, should you use `RemainAfterExit`, and will it still be possible to check the service status and use `restart`? Is the service aware of what it started and what to kill when it restarts? Ima super-duper noob at setting up linux services.

Comment: This might help: `man systemd.service | less -p 'Type=$'`